# How to know how many elements there are in a pointer array?

Tags: c

```
void print(char *arch[], int num){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<8; i++)
        printf("%s\n", *(arch+i));
}
```

In this case I knew that `arch` was formed by 8 elements, but if I didn't know how can I know it? Is there a way?

Comment: No, you have to pass that as a function argument (worse, have it defined as a global value or macro). Another way is to make the last element a sentinel value such as `NULL`.

Comment: It really looks your `num` is supposed to do exactly that. No?

Comment: Is `int num` the size of the array? If so, then you should use `for(i=0; i<num; i++)` instead of just typing `8`. You can always get the size of the array in `main` and send it into the function. As said below the information is lost once inside the function, because C sends a pointer to the first element of the array, to the function, not the array itself.

Answer (score 3):

Since arrays decay to pointers to their first element when passed as arguments to a function, length information is lost as well.

For example:

```
void bar()
{
    int data[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof data); // output: 10 * sizeof(int)
    foo(data);
}

void foo(int *arg)
{
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof arg) // output: sizeof(int *)
}
```

This is why strings are null-terminated in C: so that when pointers to strings (or arrays decayed to pointers) are passed to string-handling functions, their length can still be determined by incrementing to the null-pointer and keeping count.

There is no way of knowing the length of an array given only a pointer to the array without one of:

1. A "length" parameter
2. A sentinel value indicating the end of the array (such as the null-terminator for strings)

Comment: Should your code example have `sizeof(data)` rather than `sizeof data`? Or is there some C magic I'm not aware of?

Comment: @Catsunami `sizeof` only requires parentheses when passing a data type, not an instance of a variable (or object in C++)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can know the size of array passed to function.
As array decays to pointer to first element.

Compiler will treat.

```
void print(char *arch[], int num)
```

as

```
void print(char **arch, int num)
```

Thus when you do

```
   sizeof(arch); //It is size of pointer.
```

Solution:

1. You can pass size of array additional to function as parameter.
2. Have known value at the end of the array and loop until you find the expected value.